# Library not found for -lRNAppleAuthentication react-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in

I have tried deleting "$(inherited)" in library search paths and but it's not working[image]

Comment: Thanks, what I did was, added "RNAppleAuthentication" in library search paths in build settings. It worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with the below solution.

1. You can go to File > Workspace Settings if you are in a workspace environment or File > Project Settings for a regular project environment.
2. Then click over the little grey arrow under the Derived data section and select your project folder and close the workspace and Xcode then delete the project directory from the derived data directory.
3. Open the workspace again in Xcode and clean and rebuild the project.

Also, make sure that you have applied pod install after the package installation.

Comment: Thanks! I found a different solution after trying this.